# Why the output is integer not double?

Tags: c++

```
                           I just don't understand why...
```

---

- All of my data types are double, and if some of them are not, they're implicitly converted to double.
- No warnings and errors.

---

> - **The point is that the output of the code is  integers, not the rest of the code.**

---

- You can also see the SC in [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97586790238fdd48)
- I know that `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a header file in the standard library, just an internal implementation of GCC,but that's not the point.
- I'm sorry I can't translate the problem that's going to be solved by this piece of code because it's too long, but if you're interested,the [link](https://pintia.cn/problem-sets/994805260223102976/problems/994805261493977088).

Please help me.

**You can enter the following sample**

```
6 6 7
01234 880
a1903 199
ydjh2 200
wehu8 300
dx86w 220
missing 400
ydhfu77 99
wehu8 55
ydjh2 98
dx86w 88
a1903 86
01234 39
ydhfu77 88
a1903 66
01234 58
wehu8 84
ydjh2 82
missing 99
dx86w 81
```

**The Code**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef pair<string, array<double, 5>> PAIR;
bool cmp(PAIR x, PAIR y) {
    if (round(x.second[3]) != round(y.second[3])) return x.second[3] > y.second[3];
    else return x.first < y.first;
}
int main() {
    map<string,  array<double, 5>> student;
    int p, m, n, online, score;
    string name;
    cin >> p >> m >> n;
    while (p--) {
        cin >> name >> online;
        student[name][0] = online;
    }
    while (m--) {
        cin >> name >> score;
        if (score) student[name][1] = score;
        else student[name][4] = 1;
    }
    while (n--) {
        cin >> name >> score;
        student[name][2] = score;
        int mid = student[name][1];
        if (mid > score) student[name][3] = mid * 0.4 + score * 0.6;
        else student[name][3] = score;
    }
    for (auto p = student.begin(); p != student.end(); ) {
        if (p->second[0] < 200 || round(p->second[3]) < 60 || p->second[0] > 900) student.erase(p++);
        else p++;
    }
    vector<PAIR> answer(student.begin(), student.end());
    sort(answer.begin(), answer.end(), cmp);
    for (auto v : answer) {
        if (!v.second[1] && !v.second[4]) cout  << v.first << " " << v.second[0] << " " << -1 << " " << v.second[2] << " " << round(v.second[3]) << endl;
        else cout  << v.first << " " << v.second[0] << " " << v.second[1] << " " << v.second[2] << " " << round(v.second[3]) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*All of my data types are double, but the output is integer*" Except for `online`, `score` and `mid`, which are used for calculations  (or I think they are, I'm completely lost with all these indices and their meanings)

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` <-- Very bad idea. Don't *ever* write those two lines of code. The second can sometimes be Ok, but there is no excuse possible for the first

Comment: The `if (p->second[0] < 200 || round(p->second[3] < 60) || p->second[0] > 900) student.erase(p++);` line has issues.  You're calling `round` with a bool parameter instead of comparing the rounded result, and the statement should be `p = student.erase(p);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing only whole values because, by default, `double` are printed with a limited precision (say 6 digits) and the trailing zeroes are ignored.

Also you are using a rounded value:

```
round(v.second[3])
```

Try adding

```
#include <iomanip>
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
```